# groupby minute, hour, day, month, and year?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I'm searching a solution for my problem, but I can't find. So I'm hoping you can help me.

**Problem:**

I want to count the number of tweets in a minute.

**Dataset:**

```
    time                       sentiment
0   2018-05-02 14:28:59.281     0.8104
1   2018-05-02 14:29:03.540     0.6536
2   2018-05-02 14:29:09.570     0.0000
3   2018-05-02 14:29:10.445     0.0000
4   2018-05-02 14:29:22.245     0.0000
5   2018-05-02 14:29:23.349     0.4389
6   2018-05-02 14:29:28.329     0.2732
7   2018-05-02 14:29:30.410     0.2732
8   2018-05-02 14:29:46.122     0.0000
9   2018-05-02 14:29:53.194     -0.5562
```

I want to count the numbers of tweets in a minute and then plot them. But when I use `groupby().count()` this deletes the day, month, and year.

I got back all tweets for minute 1, but I want to get the number of tweets for `14:29  2018-05-02` and then number of tweets for `14:30  2018-05-02`.

Comment: You don't have `day`, `month`, `year` in your example, just a datetime.

Comment: Can you add example code? Are you using the `csv` and `itertools` modules or is it `pandas`? By "delete the day.." do you mean its only grouping by the hour-minute-second or is the date column disappearing from your data somehow?

Answer (score 1):

With a pandas dataframe you can `groupby` with a period of a minute and `count`. You need to make sure that `time` is a `datetime` field, e.g.:

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
```

Then simply:

```
df.groupby(df.time.dt.to_period('Min')).count()
```